# Select from named query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have issue with following query in MS Access 2013:

```
SELECT *
FROM (((
      (SELECT Stop.TAGeoID AS TAGeoID,
              Trip.TripNo AS TripNo
       FROM ((((Trip
                INNER JOIN BTStopTimes ON Trip.TripNo = BTStopTimes.TripNumber)
               INNER JOIN TripsTxt ON (Trip.TripNo = TripsTxt.trip_id
                                       AND Left(TripsTxt.shape_id, 3) <> 'ELD'))
              INNER JOIN PatternDetail ON Trip.PatternID = PatternDetail.PatternID
              AND BTStopTimes.Sequence = PatternDetail.StopSortOrder)
             INNER JOIN Stop ON Stop.GeoID = PatternDetail.GeoID)) AS t3
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT F10,
              F16
       FROM PatternStopsRaw
       WHERE F16 <> ''
       GROUP BY F10,
                F16)R ON R.F10 = t3.TAGeoID)
   LEFT JOIN Timepoint ON Timepoint.PlaceID = R.F16)
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM t3
     INNER JOIN TripDetail ON t3.TripNo = TripDetail.TripNo)TripTripDetail ON (Timepoint.TimePointID = TripTripDetail.TimepointID))
```

It says that there is syntax error

```
The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query t3. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly
```

It seems that Access does not allow selecting from the named query in the same query.

Any suggestions?

PS: * are used only for testing purposes, I'll remove them once I have working query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears that Access does not recognize the [t3] alias at that level. Perhaps you could try creating the query...

```
SELECT Stop.TAGeoID AS TAGeoID,
              Trip.TripNo AS TripNo
       FROM ((((Trip
                INNER JOIN BTStopTimes ON Trip.TripNo = BTStopTimes.TripNumber)
               INNER JOIN TripsTxt ON (Trip.TripNo = TripsTxt.trip_id
                                       AND Left(TripsTxt.shape_id, 3) <> 'ELD'))
              INNER JOIN PatternDetail ON Trip.PatternID = PatternDetail.PatternID
              AND BTStopTimes.Sequence = PatternDetail.StopSortOrder)
             INNER JOIN Stop ON Stop.GeoID = PatternDetail.GeoID)
```

...as a saved query in Access, name it [t3], and then just reference that in your main query.

Comment: It was my option, but I was trying to avoid saved queries. Anyway, since you answer is correct, I'll accept it. Thank you!